# onclick inside Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, dynamically-generated

I have an ajax call that on success create an element. When the element is clicked, a spinning gif needs to be displayed while another action is being done (creating jquery datatables). Then the gif should disappear. In my case everything works except for the fact that the gif is loading after the jquery datatables is created and therefore only shown very briefly. I want it to start as soon as I click the element, but this is not the case.

```
ajax{
element.create();
element.click(){
      startLoadingGif();

      drawJqueryDataTables();

      stopLoadingGif();
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this. `startLoadingGif()` before the request is made and `stopLoadingGif();` after the completion (success or failure) of the request:

```
   startLoadingGif();
     $.ajax({
      ...
      complete: function (data) {
          stopLoadingGif()
        }
     });
```

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
      ...
      complete: function (data) {
           element.create();
           element.click()
           startLoadingGif();
           drawJqueryDataTables(); //Or you can make this a promise if it takes a longer time and after that is resolved you can stop the spinner. Or,
           window.setTimeout(()=>{
             stopLoadingGif();
           }, 2000)

     });
```

Comment: I think I was not completely clear here. The element is shown after the ajax is complete. I want to show the loadingGif after ajax is complete and by clicking the generated element. I don't want to show is the whole time the ajax is running.

Comment: And when would you stop then?

Comment: after drawJqueryDataTables(); It is in the sample pseudocode

Comment: So that should work. Where are you facing the issue? Do you just want to delay the spinner?

Comment: I don't want to delay it. For some reason the loader doesn't show up. It first does drawJqueryDataTables(); and then shows loadingGif

Comment: I suspect the method might be executing asynchronously. Is that? If you show the actual code, I might say something

Comment: Yes drawJqueryDataTables(); is executing asynchronously and there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Well, still the loader should start immediately if that's not async.

Comment: No the loader is not async, it is simple loader built on CSS and HTML